# A question on Alexander subbase theorem

Tags: general-topology

[Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander's_sub-base_theorem?wprov=sfsi1)
entry on Alexander subbase theorem:
Let X be a topological space with a subbasis B. If every cover of X by elements from B has a finite subcover, then the space is compact.
My proof:Since every open set can be expressed by the union of some elements of B, every open cover can be expressed as an open cover by elements of B, which has a finite subcover.So any open cover of X has a finite subcover and hence the space is compact.
My question is why the proof of Alexander subbase theorem in Wikipedia is so tedious？
Any wrong in my proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the second paragraph in the proof, where they use $S$ is a subbase: there for some $x \in U$ (open) we have finitely many $S_1, \ldots S_n$ such that $x \in \cap_{i=1}^n S_i \subseteq U$, because **finite intersections** from $S$ form a base.

Your own observation proves the easier fact for a base: for compactness it also suffices to only consider covers with elements from a fixed base for the topology.

We do need some AC-related fact, like Zorn, to prove this theorem, because Alexander's subbase theorem/lemma easily implies Tychonoff's theorem (which again implies AC).

I wrote down a similar proof to Wikipedia's in full detail [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1747).

Comment: Wow, very useful ! Thanks a lot

Comment: The link to your proof has unfortunately died by this time. Can it be resurrected ?

Comment: @TomCollinge It's archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160826064602/http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2005;task=show_msg;msg=1747)

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

No, not every open set is necessarily the union of elements of $B$, since $B$ is not a **basis** for the topology of $X$ but a sub-basis.
Each open set is the union of **finite intersections** of elements of $B$.

Comment: Since the question ended with "Any wrong in my proof?" the "No" at the beginning of the answer could be misleading.  Except for that one word, this answer is exactly what the OP needs.